# hasMany relationship with multiple models?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Here's the problem:

```
/**
 * Get all of the clothes for the Selling
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function clothes(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cloth::class);
}
```

I need to make this relationship accept more than one type of model, something like this:

```
/**
 * Get all of the products for the Selling
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function products(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany([Cloth::class, Accessory::class]);
}
```

At first i thought a polymorphic relation would do the trick but i don't think it will.
Should i make a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by defining another relationship in the model:

```
 /**
 * Get all of the accessories for the Selling
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function accessories(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Accessory::class);
}
```

And then merge them with a function:

```
/**
 * Get all of the products for the Selling
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function products(): Collection
{
    return $this->clothes->merge($this->accessories);
}
```